# Dismiss a popup from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am writing an application which is having an activity and I am launching a pop up ( pop up I have implemented in another class which is not an activity).
In my main activity I have code to display the popup when there is an event. I am successfully able to do that. But I need to cancel the popup when I get another event. ( I will get this event only in the main activity). 
How can I finish the popup from the main activity when I receive the event?

Answer (score 2):

create a public method in the class where you have created the popUP(dialog) and write inside it as

```
public void dismissDialog(){
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

then whenever you want to remove the dialog call this method...

Comment: Hi, My main activity and the popup class are in different packages. So how can i do it.

Comment: So why will that affect? You are able to access the method show the popup... then you can also access the method to dismiss it...

Comment: public void showMessage(Context c, final String title,
            final String s) {
        
        
        mContext = c;


        final AlertDialog.Builder aBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        aBuilder.setTitle(title);
        aBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        // aBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        aBuilder.setMessage(s);

Answer (score 1):

If this pop up is a dialog you can do it with

`dialog.cancel();`

Comment: Hi, My main activity and the popup class are in different packages. So how can i do it.

Comment: public void showMessage(Context c, final String title,
            final String s) {
        mContext = c;
        final AlertDialog.Builder aBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        aBuilder.setTitle(title);
        aBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        // aBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        aBuilder.setMessage(s);aBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();

Comment: aBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                //  r.stop();
                showNotification(mContext);
            }

        });

        dlg = aBuilder.show();
        MyThread runnable = new MyThread();
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        setDlg(dlg);
       // dlg.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Comment: t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            dismisspop();
        }
        }, 30000);
        public static void dismisspop() {
         dlg.dismiss(); 
         mMediaPlayer.stop();
        // r.stop();
         System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~$");
         showNotification(mContext);
         t.cancel();

Answer (score 0):

```
final AlertDialog.Builder aBuilder;

//constructor(Context c){//mContext = c;}

public void showMessage(final String title, final String s) { 

        aBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext); 
        aBuilder.setTitle(title); 
        aBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); 
        // aBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon); 
        aBuilder.setMessage(s);
    }

public void dismissMessage() { 
        aBuilder.dismiss();
    }
```